# R code for finding determinant of a nxn matrix is not working for n>=4

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, matrix

## Determinant of a nxn matrix

```
dmat<- function(x=matrix()){
n<- nrow(x)
s<- 0
   der<- function(x=matrix()){
     a<- x[1,1]*x[2,2]
     b<- x[1,2]*x[2,1]
     d<- a-b
     return(d)
   }
   
   if(n>2){
     for(i in 1:(n-2)){
       for(j in 1:n){
         if(j%%2==0){p<- -1
         }else{p<- 1}
         s<- s + p*x[i,j]*dmat(x[-i,-j])
       }
     }
   }else{
     s<- der(x)
   }
   return(s)
 }
```

### Example:

> x<- matrix(c(2,3,5,8,9,7,4,7,8),3,3)
>
> dmat(x)
>
> 38
>
> y<- matrix(c(1,5,8,4,9,6,7,5,4,8,9,4,4,2,6,8),4,4)
>
> dmat(y)
>
> 0

Whereas the answer to `dmat(y)` is `354`
*Although I know there is a `det()` function which can be used.

Comment: I think some "rubber ducky" debugging could work well here. What algorithm are you using for the determinant? Can you link to it and describe in words how your code implements it?

Comment: I think you're doing too much looping.  I believe you're trying to go across a row (or column) and then multiply the value times the determinent of whatever remains after removing that row/column.  But you only need a single loop to do this.  You're calculating things too many times once you get enough dimensions.

Comment: @Gregor you are right, I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you should have only one single loop rather than two loops. If you remove the outer `for (i in ...) {...}`, you will definitely get the correct determinant.

The fixed up looks like below

```
dmat <- function(x = matrix()) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    s <- 0
    der <- function(x = matrix()) {
        a <- x[1, 1] * x[2, 2]
        b <- x[1, 2] * x[2, 1]
        d <- a - b
        return(d)
    }

    if (n > 2) {
        for (j in 1:n) {
            if (j %% 2 == 0) {
                p <- -1
            } else {
                p <- 1
            }
            s <- s + p * x[1, j] * dmat(x[-1, -j])
        }
    } else {
        s <- der(x)
    }
    return(s)
}
```

or a more efficient and concise variant

```
dmat <- function(x) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    s <- 0
    if (n > 2) {
        p <- 1
        for (j in 1:n) {
            s <- s + p * x[1, j] * Recall(x[-1, -j])
            p <- -p
        }
        return(s)
    } else {
        return(x[1, 1] * x[2, 2] - x[1, 2] * x[2, 1])
    }
}
```

and you will see that

```
> y <- matrix(c(1, 5, 8, 4, 9, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 2, 6, 8), 4, 4)

> dmat(y)
[1] 354
```

---

## Benchmark

Timing for comparing several implementations of determinant

```
dmat1 <- function(x) {
    n <- nrow(x)
    s <- 0
    if (n > 2) {
        p <- 1
        for (j in 1:n) {
            s <- s + p * x[1, j] * Recall(x[-1, -j])
            p <- -p
        }
    } else {
        return(x[1, 1] * x[2, 2] - x[1, 2] * x[2, 1])
    }
}

dmat2 <- function(m) {
    if (length(m) == 1) {
        return(m)
    }
    sum(
        unlist(
            lapply(
                seq_len(ncol(m)),
                \(j) (-1)^(1 + j) * m[1, j] * dmat2(m[-1, -j])
            )
        )
    )
}

y <- matrix(c(1, 5, 8, 4, 9, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 2, 6, 8), 4, 4)


set.seed(0)

y <- matrix(runif(36), 6)

microbenchmark(
    f0 = det(y),
    f1 = dmat1(y),
    f2 = dmat2(y),
    unit = "relative"
)
```

and you will see

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean    median       uq      max neval
   f0   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000   1.00000   1.0000 1.000000   100
   f1 153.0312 131.0123 11.76908  42.63068  28.7871 1.305825   100
   f2 541.5000 479.7716 42.39508 162.31061 125.4527 1.544381   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursion method (see the [reference](https://piazza.com/class_profile/get_resource/hz50nc5muxb1r4/i1w7zp4mdhg73r#:%7E:text=S.R.%20DOTY-,The%20determinant%20function%20det%20is%20a%20function%20from%20n%20%C3%97,a%20certain%20submatrix%20of%20A.)) to implement the ***determinant*** of matrix:

[image]

## Warning

It is just one of possible implementations to calculate the matrix determinant, not considering the efficiency. It would be **dramatically slow** when running with large matrices! ***Be Careful!***

## code

```
dmat <- function(m) {
    if (length(m) == 1) {
        return(m)
    }
    sum(
        unlist(
            lapply(
                seq_len(ncol(m)),
                \(j) (-1)^(1 + j) * m[1, j] * dmat2(m[-1, -j])
            )
        )
    )
}
```

and you will see

```
> y <- matrix(c(1, 5, 8, 4, 9, 6, 7, 5, 4, 8, 9, 4, 4, 2, 6, 8), 4, 4)

> dmat(y)
[1] 354
```

and a random test

```
> set.seed(0)

> m <- matrix(runif(36), 6)

> det(m)
[1] 0.02253246

> dmat(m)
[1] 0.02253246
```